# How to get all Leases or Http Client from VaultSharp?

Tags: security, .net-core, hashicorp-vault, c#-6.0, vaultsharp

I am using `HashiCorp Vault 1.10.0` to maintain secrets and for this, I am using `VaultSharp` in `C# .Net Core 6.0`.

I am new to `VaultSharp` and I have ask about it that how can I get **Leases** from the `VaultSharp` (I tried but not able to find such functionality in the the `VaulSharp`), in case, if there is no such functionality then is there any way to get Its `HttpClient`, so that I could pass the Lease API URL?

**And here is the scenario why do I need this?**

I am generating the dynamic DB credentials from the Vault and therefore I need to know when they are going to expired, for this reason I need to know its lease information that tells us its creation and expiration time.

Otherwise, I have to create a new `Httpclient` that will call the `Hashicorp` Vault API and gets the Leases from it but I want to use `VaultSharp` to maintain consistency.

Please advise.

**Thank you**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have resolved the issue by

```
var res = await VaultClient.V1.System.GetLeaseAsync(dbCreds.LeaseId);
```